# Radius of the circle...

Tags: geometry

can you please give an idea of how can I solve the following problem. Given that $|AO|=\sqrt5$ and that $|OC|=\sqrt10$ find the length of the circle with the center in point $O$.

Here's a picture ($it's$ $not$ $perfect,$  $excuse$ $me$  )
[image]

Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: What do you mean *length of the circle*? Perimeter? Diameter? Radius?

Comment: Perimeter , excuse me in my language is called the length of the circle, but its the same as  perimeter

Comment: is $ \angle AOC = 90 ^ {\circ} $ ???

Comment: So why is the question title about the *radius*?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche  The radius of the circle is related to the formula of the perimeter of the circle, so I want to find the radius first, and , consequently, the perimeter is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the length of the tangent from $C$ to the circle and $b$ the length of the tangent from $A$ to the circle.  From the three separate right-angled triangles shown we have
$$a^2+r^2=10\ ,\quad b^2+r^2=5\ ,\quad (a+r)^2+(b+r)^2=(a+b)^2\ .$$
Expand the third equation and cancel obvious bits to get
$$ar+r^2+br=ab\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Now multiply by $a-b$ and do a bit of algebra to get
$$(a^2-b^2)r+(a-b)r^2=a^2b-ab^2\ .$$
Use the first two equations to eliminate all the $a^2$ and $b^2$ terms,
$$5r+(a-b)r^2=b(10-r^2)-a(5-r^2)=10b-5a+(a-b)r^2$$
and so
$$r=2b-a\ .$$
Substituting back into $(*)$ gives
$$(2b-a)(3b)=ab$$
and so $b=2a/3$, $r=a/3$.  Hence
$$10=a^2+r^2=10r^2\ ,$$
which gives $r=1$.  So the circle has radius $1$ and circumference $2\pi$.

Comment: Of course it should be.  How did I miss that??  Thanks!